# How can I remove a property from a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

here I am creating a javascript object like this:

`let obj = { "how": "fetch", "method": "get", "url": "^http://.*"};`

And i want to remove the property `url` to end up with new `obj` as follows:

`let obj = { "how": "fetch", "method": "get"};`

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Please spent some time researching if your question has already been answered here, there is an almost identical question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one line.

```
delete obj.url
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer functional JavaScript, you can use object destructuring:

```
const { url, ...objWithoutUrl } = obj;
```

This has the performance disadvantage of creating a new object, but the stability advantage of not mutating the original object. When you pass objects between functions, it can lead to undesired effects when a function mutates the object with `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete obj.url;
// or you can try with
delete obj['url'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is set a variable with the key that you want.

> const someName = "objectKey";

and then use the delete method

> delete array[objectKey];

in your case it would be like that:

```
const key = "url";
delete obj[key];
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer, SO is about learning too.

Comment: I explain a bit more hope is better like that